# Alias settings not "sticking" when running Fedora in Parallels

Tags: linux, fedora, bash-alias

Recently set up a Fedora 15 installation using the latest version of Parallels. Everything *seems* to be working fine, save for a particularly odd quirk. Whenever I set up an alias using something like  `alias homessh='ssh -X user@server.home.com'` it doesn't seem to get retained once I close the Terminal.

Running 'alias' immediately afterward shows it on the list of aliases available to the system, and actually running said alias works. But if I close the Terminal, either by 'exit' or closing the window, its gone when I start up the next session.

Anyone have an idea what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They never do. Put them in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: ...that probably should have been obvious.